# Cocos2d, using greater than and less than limits on an integer value to display a sprite

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, flappy-bird-clone

I'm using cocos2d to create a DNA themed Flappy Bird style game (long story, don't expect to make any money off of it). I'm trying to create a system of rewarding a "medal" based on the score reached on a certain round. I'm using and greater than and less than methods to indicate whether or not a certain "medal" should be received. However, all of my medals show up at the same time instead of individually based on score. Here is the applicable code:

```
NSInteger _points;

-(BOOL)ccPhysicsCollisionBegin:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair hero:(CCNode *)hero goal:(CCNode *)goal {
    [goal removeFromParent];
    _points++;
    _scoreLabel.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", _points];
    [self saveState];
    [self loadSavedState];
if (_points > _highScore) {
    _highScore = _points;
}
return TRUE;
}

- (void)gameOver {
    if (!_gameOver) {
        _scrollSpeed = 0.f;
        _gameOver = TRUE;
        _restartButton.visible = TRUE;
        _menuButton.visible = TRUE;
        _gameOverText.visible = TRUE;
        _score.visible = TRUE;
        _highScoreValue.visible = TRUE;
        _highScoreLabel.visible = TRUE;
        _medal.visible = TRUE;
        if (9 < _points < 20) {
            _uracil.visible = TRUE;
            _uracilLabel.visible = TRUE;
        }
        if (19 < _points < 30) {
            _thymine.visible = TRUE;
            _thymineLabel.visible = TRUE;
        }
        if (29 < _points < 40) {
            _cytosine.visible = TRUE;
            _cytosineLabel.visible = TRUE;
        }
        if (39 < _points < 50) {
            _guanine.visible = TRUE;
            _guanineLabel.visible = TRUE;
        }
        if (49 < _points < 60) {
            _adenine.visible = TRUE;
            _adenineLabel.visible = TRUE;
        }
        _scoreLabel.position = ccp(260, 358);
        _hero.physicsBody.allowsRotation = FALSE;
        [_hero stopAllActions];
        CCActionMoveBy *moveBy = [CCActionMoveBy actionWithDuration:0.2f position:ccp(-5, 5)];
        CCActionInterval *reverseMovement = [moveBy reverse];
        CCActionSequence *shakeSequence = [CCActionSequence actionWithArray:@[moveBy, reverseMovement]];
        CCActionEaseBounce *bounce = [CCActionEaseBounce actionWithAction:shakeSequence];
        [self runAction:bounce];
    }
}
```

How can I make it so that the "medals" show up when they are supposed to based on score?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace these

```
if (9 < _points < 20)
```

With

```
if (_points > 9 && _points < 20)
```